# Camel: dynamic rest uri path with EL in DSL not possible?

Tags: http, apache-camel, url-routing, el, dsl

I'm new to camel and use it for http routing configured by Spring DSL with the camel servlet. Unfortunately a routing to "to" like this not works:

```
<to uri="https://host/path/${headers.pname1}/2016/11?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
```

where ${headers.pname1} is a http query string parameter from the http input on servlet.

How to use expression language in the uri path?

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment by Claus Ibsen,

use the extra tag "toD" instead of "to":

```
<toD uri="https://host/path/${headers.pname1}/2016/11?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
```

Probably they made a second tag for performance reasons.